# General solution to $(\sqrt{3}-1)\cos x+(\sqrt{3}+1)\sin x=2$

Tags: trigonometry

$(\sqrt{3}-1)\cos x+(\sqrt{3}+1)\sin x=2$ is said to have a general solution of $x=2n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{12}$.

**My Approach:**

Considering the equation as 
$$
a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\Big(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x\Big)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\big(\sin y.\cos x+\cos y.\sin x\big)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.\sin(y+x)=2
$$

$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sin y$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos y$.
$$
{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}\\\tan y=a/b=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{\sin(\pi/3-\pi/4)}{\sin(\pi/3+\pi/4)}=\frac{\sin(\pi/3-\pi/4)}{\cos(\pi/3-\pi/4)}=\tan(\pi/3-\pi/4)\implies y=\pi/3-\pi/4=\pi/12
$$
Substituting for $y$,
$$
2\sqrt{2}.\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}+x)=2\implies \sin(\frac{\pi}{12}+x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\\implies \frac{\pi}{12}+x=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{12}
$$

What's going wrong with the approach ?

Comment: your question does not give the answer you mentioned. But, luckily on reversing the signs, I got your answer.

Comment: @Rohan thnx..i noted tht b4..thts why i made that error in the question in the first place. Could you pls verify my approach here.

Comment: It is always better to take $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos y$ approach according to me, but your answer is otherwise very perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Our hint is**: $a\cos \theta +b\sin \theta =c$.

Given: $(\sqrt{3}-1)\cos \theta +(\sqrt{3}+1)\sin \theta =2$.

Let $(\sqrt{3}-1) = r\cos \alpha$ and $(\sqrt{3}+1) =r\sin \alpha$.

Then $r\cos \alpha \cos \theta + r\sin \alpha \sin \theta =2 \Rightarrow r\cos(\theta-\alpha) =2 \Rightarrow \cos(\theta-\alpha) =\frac{2}{r}$.

Now, $r =\sqrt{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2 +(\sqrt{3}+1)^2} = \sqrt{8} =2\sqrt{2}$.

Thus, $\cos(\theta-\alpha) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Also, $\tan \alpha =\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1} = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3} +\frac{\pi}{4}) \Rightarrow \alpha =\frac{5\pi}{12}$.

---

Thus:$(\theta-\alpha) =2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$. Giving, $\theta = 2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{5\pi}{12}.$

Comment: I'm srry.....pls check my edit... it is $a\cos x+b\sin x=(\sqrt{3}-1)\cos x+(\sqrt{3}+1)\sin x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider system \begin{align} (\sqrt 3 - 1)\cos x+(\sqrt 3+ 1)\sin x &= 2\\ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x &= 1\end{align} Geometrically, you are looking for intersection of a line and unit circle, so we are expecting at most two solutions (see [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7B(Sqrt%5B3%5D%20-%201)%20u%20%2B%20(1%20%2B%20Sqrt%5B3%5D)%20v%20%3D%3D%202,%20%20%20%20u%5E2%20%2B%20v%5E2%20%3D%3D%201%7D,%20%7Bu,%20-2,%202%7D,%20%7Bv,%20-2,%202%20%7D%5D)). Thus, we can safely square the first equation and eliminate extra solutions later. Doing this we get: \begin{align}(4-2\sqrt 3)\cos^2x+4\cos x\sin x+(4+2\sqrt 3)\sin^2 x &= 4\\ 2\sin 2x -2\sqrt 3\cos 2x &= 0\\ \tan 2x &= \sqrt 3\\ 2x &= \pi/3+k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z\\ x &= \pi/6+k\pi/2,\ k\in\Bbb Z\end{align} Now, we eliminate solutions not in first or second quadrant to finally get $$x = \pi/6+2k\pi,\ x = 2\pi/3+2k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

converting the given equation in $$\tan$$ we get
$${\frac { \left( 1+\sqrt {3} \right)  \left( 1- \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}+2\,{\frac { \left( \sqrt {3}-1 \right) \tan \left( x/2
 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}-2=0
$$
simplifying and factorizing we obtain
$$-1/3\,{\frac { \left( \sqrt {3}+3 \right)  \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right) +2-\sqrt {3} \right)  \left( 3\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) -
\sqrt {3} \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
=0$$
thus you have to solve
$$- \left( \sqrt {3}+3 \right)  \left( -\tan \left( x/2 \right) -2+
\sqrt {3} \right)  \left( -3\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) +\sqrt {3}
 \right) 
=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sqrt{3}-1)\cos x+(\sqrt{3}+1)\sin x=2$$
divide by $2\sqrt{2}$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\cos x+\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
now use

> $$\cos a \cos b+\sin a \sin b=\cos (a-b)$$

$$
\cos^2 a+\sin^2 a=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2=1
$$
and the fact that $$a=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1})=\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

we have $$\cos(\frac{5\pi}{12}-x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$$
which gives
$$\frac{5\pi}{12}-x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+2k \pi$$
$$\boxed{x=2k\pi+\frac{2\pi}{3},\quad x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

Comment: Something went wrong. Evaluate your solutions and you will get $\sqrt 2$ instead of $2$.

Comment: @msm $\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{4}\big)^2+\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{4}\big)^2$ is not equal to $1$, thts the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $(\tan A-\tan45^\circ)\cos x+(\tan A+\tan45^\circ)\sin x=\sec A$

$\cos(x+A+45^\circ)=\cos45^\circ$